# Will there be an infinite number of critical points in this case? (maxima minima for a function of two variables)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, maxima-minima

**Question:**

Locate all relative maxima, relative minima and saddle points (if any) for the function

$$f(x,y)=y\sqrt{x} - y^2-2x+7y$$

**My attempt:**

$$f_x(x,y)=\frac{y}{2\sqrt{x}}-2$$

$$f_y(x,y)=\sqrt{x}-2y+7$$

For the critical point $(x_0, y_0)$, $f_x(x_0,y_0)=0$ and $f_y(x_0,y_0)=0$. Following this line of reasoning we can find one critical point $(x_0,y_0)=(1,4)$. I will not expand upon that.

My interest is in $f_x(x,y)$ being undefined. Have a look at this definition from Anton:

> 13.8.5 Definition A point $(x_0, y_0)$ in the domain of a function $f(x, y)$ is called a critical point of the function if $f_x(x_0, y_0) = 0$ and
> $f_y(x_0, y_0) = 0$ or if one or both partial derivatives do not exist at
> $(x_0, y_0)$.

$f_x(x,y)$ does not exist for $x=0$. So, let our second critical point be $(0, k)$. Now, how do I find the value of $k$? It seems to me that $(0, k)$ represents an infinite number of points. So, does the above function have an infinite number of critical points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've already answered your own question. As you point out yourself, any point $(0,y)$ with $y\neq0$ (to avoid $0/0$) lies in the domain of $f$ and leads to nonexistence of the partial derivative with respect to the first argument. Hence, such a point satisfies the definition of a critical point you stated. (Whether all those points are relevant for your problem is a different story.)